# How to connect elasticsearch with nodejs

Tags: jquery, node.js, elasticsearch, kibana

I need someone's help to do a query in the script as I'm unsure how to get timestamp by per second instead of by 5 seconds. Anyone kind to help?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for the best question possible to let the reader see what you have done so far and what do you exactly do struggle at ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [driver](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js) to connect Elasticsearch in Nodejs